# Grails - Get reference to logged user in views

Tags: grails, spring-security, gsp

I'm developing an application that requires to restrict data to specific users. I'm using Spring Security Core to handle users management. What I need is to obtain a reference to the logged user in order to make some filtering operations. Consider this code:

```
    class Cliente {
        Deposito deposito

        String ci
        String nombre
        String telefono
        String celular

        static constraints = {
        ...
        }
    }

class Empresa {
    Deposito deposito

    String tipoDeEmpresa
    String nombreDeEmpresa
    String departamento
    String provincia
    String municipio    

    static constraints = {
        ...
    }
}

class SecUser implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1

    Deposito deposito

    String nombre
    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled = true
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    ...
}
```

I need help with this fragment of GSP (generated `form.gsp` view) code:

```
<div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: clienteInstance, field: 'empresa', 'error')} required">
    <label for="empresa">
        <g:message code="cliente.empresa.label" default="Empresa"/>
        <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
    </label>    
    <g:select id="empresa" name="empresa.id" from="${org.socymet.proveedor.Empresa.findAllByDeposito(loggedUser.deposito,[sort: 'nombreDeEmpresa'])}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${clienteInstance?.empresa?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
</div>
```

In the line where the `Empresa.findAllByDeposito(loggedUser.deposito,[sort: 'nombreDeEmpresa'])` finder is called I need to replace the loggedUser with an efficient and correct code to obtain the referce to the current logged user.

I was trying to implement a method in the `Cliente` domain class but I think it is not a good practice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What I need is to get a list of Empresas given an Deposito (to which belongs the logged user).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current user using...

```
<sec:ifLoggedIn>
   <sec:username />
</sec:ifLoggedIn>
```

You can make decisions based on roles like...

```
<sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_YOUR_ROLE">
    // do stuff
</sec:ifAnyGranted>
```

Roles are prefixed by default with ROLE_ when accessing like above, this would be restricting based on the role named YOUR_ROLE

Comment: I can use these tags to filter contents, but how could you use them as parameter with the finder `Empresa.findAllByDeposito(loggedUser.deposito,[sort: 'nombreDeEmpresa'])`? This is my main problem.